# How to get rid of partial CSS animation is restarted after v-for rendered list order updated in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a list of data and template will use this list to draw list of blocks which containing time bar for each.

The order of list could be updated at **anytime**, and I found that for each time the list order is updated, some time bar animation is being **restarted unexpectedly**.

Here is the jsFiddle to simulate the behavior, can anyone suggest me the solution to get rid of it?
Thanks!

**JsFiddle Code**:

https://jsfiddle.net/tklfiddle/30z4km8f/7/

Vue Template

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>TimeBars:</h2>
  <button @click="reOrder">
    Shuffle
  </button>
  <ul class="listWrapper">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in list" class="row itemTest" :id="item.id" :key="item.id">
      <div class="timeBarContainer">
        <div class="timeBar" :style="{animationDuration: item.duration+ 's'}">
        </div>
        <div class="timeBarText">
          {{item.id}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{list}}
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list: [
      { id: "bar1", done: false, duration: 10 },
      { id: "bar2", done: false, duration: 10 },
      { id: "bar3", done: true, duration: 10 },
      { id: "bar4", done: true, duration: 10 }
    ]
  },
  mounted(){
        console.log("DEBUG: mounted", $("body"));
    $(".listWrapper").on('DOMNodeRemoved', function(e) {
      console.log(e.target, ' was removed');
    });
  },
  methods: {
    reOrder: function(){
        this.list = shuffle(this.list);
      //this.list.pop();
      console.log("DEBUG: this.list:", JSON.stringify(this.list));
      function shuffle(array) {
          var currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
          // While there remain elements to shuffle...
          while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex--;
            // And swap it with the current element.
            [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
              array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
          }

          return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
        }
      }
    }
})
```

SCSS

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
  >div{
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.timeBarContainer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.timeBar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  animation: timeBarAnimation 0s linear normal forwards;
}
.timeBarText{
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes timeBarAnimation {
    0% {
        width: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
    }
}
```

---

**CodeSandBox Code**:

Here is one more example coded with codeSandBox,
As you can see the TimeBar component didnt get unmounted after shuffled but the css animation is being restart which is unexpected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-smoke-n806b?file=/src/components/TimeBar.vue

Comment: I like the question. I think (I really do not know VUE well) that VUE (sometimes?) re-renders the `<li>` elements and the original elements `<li>` (with original animation) are lost (I can observe it with chrome dev tool -> animation tab). In React I can memoize elements. Is there anything like that in VUE as well? I was trying to solve it with flexbox order. It kinda works (animation stays) but the transition animation is not smooth (at least not in chrome)... https://jsfiddle.net/q329zvs1/2/  (please ignore the `document.queries` lol). I hope someone will find a solution.

Comment: Great comment, *memoization* is an excellent keyword. Indeed there [seems to be memoization stuff in Vue](https://learnvue.co/tutorials/v-once-v-memo) - sadly I read this after implementing a work-around, so I can't confirm whether this is a fix...

Comment: How do you use v-once or v-memo to fix the problem? Could you also provide the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a (mediocre, situational) work-around:

- **have a fixed-length array** of empty objects containing a property like `active: false` and other properties for the data you need, say `my-custom-content = ''`
- generate this empty list early, e.g. in `mounted` (depending on what you are doing)
- have a `v-for` acting on this array, but only actually render any given object in the array when it's active (use `v-if=object.active` in a child object of your `v-for` object or go for a filtered list in the `v-for`)
- if you have something to display, **directly overwrite a specific *property* of a specific object in the array**. Do not `push` or `splice`.
- Vue does not register this as a change to the list itself, so the `v-for` is not regenerated, so CSS animations do not get reset (data is still dynamically changed, though)

**This is quite dirty**, if you have complex requirements you are basically going to re-implement list operations, which is terrible, however for my simple use case it works and maybe it will for yours, too :)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this can help you :

**[Update Array and Object in Vuejs](https://medium.com/@miladmeidanshahi/update-array-and-object-in-vuejs-a283983fe5ba)**

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pick up these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely. Vue provides a convenience method arr.$set(index, value) which is syntax sugar for arr.splice(index, 1, value).

Comment: I didn't get your point, my question is not about how to reactively update the list, as you can see the lowest part of my jsfiddle and codesanbox, the datas are reactively updated, my question is, why those animation are being reset after the array list is reactively updated.